# Hibernate Error( "object references an unsaved transient instance" or "Duplicate entry"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a big problem with my code:

Here is my UserAccount Class:
https://github.com/Bodyash/pizzaria/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bodyash/pizzaria/bean/UserAccount.java

Here is my UserAccountRole class:
https://github.com/Bodyash/pizzaria/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bodyash/pizzaria/bean/UserAccountRole.java

I`m using @ManyToMany relationship, because user can have multiple roles, for example:

Username: testuser

Roles: ADMIN, DBA

But when i creating a new UserAccount.class and tried to persist this Entity with role User - i have error:

```
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    account
    (PASSWORD, SSO_ID) 
values
    (?, ?)


Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    account_role
    (TYPE) 
values
    (?)

ERROR: Duplicate entry 'USER' for key 'UK_p90gi6g6phk4nka444jkxi9ik'
```

It's all because my table (account_role) is populated with this Types:
`USER, DBA, ADMIN` and i don`t need to WRITE this roles to TABLE AGAIN, but Hibernate ORM tried to do it. I just need to Write a new User to Table and use table account_account_role to know, which roles have this user.
Sorry for my English, i just need a little help.

UPDATE:

Full stack trace of exception:
pastebin.c o m / k061xxyV (Sorry, i cant post more than 2 links)

Comment: what is the error or share the full stack-trace it may be helpful. suppose you insert values via the appication.

Comment: Here is full stack trace:

https://pastebin.com/k061xxyV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an Error.
In AccountController:

Wrong WAY:

```
        HashSet<UserAccountRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
        UserAccountRole uar = new UserAccountRole("USER");
        userRoles.add(uar);
        user.setUserProfiles(userRoles);
```

FIXED:

```
        HashSet<UserAccountRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
        UserAccountRole uar = userAccountRoleService.findByType("USER");
        userRoles.add(uar);
        user.setUserProfiles(userRoles);
```

Must retrive AccountRole from Database.

Answer (score 0):

Every many-to-many association has two sides, the owning side and the non-owning, or inverse, side. The join table is specified on the owning side.

Move your `@JoinTable` to UserAccountRole. In `UserAccountRole` entity, try using `@Enumerated(STRING)`so that the field you set is persisted as an enumerated type. ex:

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "account_account_role", 
       joinColumns = { @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "account_ID") }, 
       inverseJoinColumns = { @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "account_role_ID") })
    @Enumerated(STRING)
    private UserAccountRoleType type;
```

And on the inverse side `UserAccount`  you should add the following:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="type")
private Set<UserAccountRole> userRoles;
```

Comment: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Attribute [com.bodyash.pizzaria.bean.UserAccountRole.type] was annotated as enumerated, but its java type is not an enum [java.lang.String]